# Random RGB generator - why am I getting two separate answers?

Tags: javascript, rgb

I'm attempting to create a game where you have to guess a randomly generated RGB on the screen with it's randomly generated visual counterpart on the screen out of 3 possible selections. For some reason, even though both the RGB value on the screen and the matching color both are assigned to the same variable, 2/10 times I get back a different RGB value for the color, not matching the typed out RGB value. The problem occurs in the 'DOMContentLoaded' event listener.

```js
const easyBtn = document.querySelector('.easy'),
      hardBtn = document.querySelector('.hard'),
      rgb = document.querySelector('.rgb'),
      rand1 = Math.round(Math.random()*300),
      rand2 = Math.round(Math.random()*300),
      rand3 = Math.round(Math.random()*300),
      rand = `rgb(${rand1}, ${rand2}, ${rand3})`,
      color1 = document.querySelector('.color1'),
      color2 = document.querySelector('.color2'),
      color3 = document.querySelector('.color3'),
      colorsDiv = document.querySelector('.colors'),
      newGame = document.querySelector('.new'),
      rand4 = Math.round(Math.random()*301),
      rand5 = Math.round(Math.random()*301),
      rand6 = Math.round(Math.random()*301),
      randd = `rgb(${rand4}, ${rand5}, ${rand6})`,
      rand7 = Math.round(Math.random()*302),
      rand8 = Math.round(Math.random()*302),
      rand9 = Math.round(Math.random()*302),
      randdd = `rgb(${rand7}, ${rand8}, ${rand9})`,
      // Easy Random Colors
      easyRand1 = Math.round(Math.random()*100),
      easyRand2 = Math.round(Math.random()*100),
      easyRand3 = Math.round(Math.random()*100),
      easyRand = `rgb(${easyRand1}, ${easyRand2}, ${easyRand3})`;
      easyRand4 = Math.round(Math.random()*101),
      easyRand5 = Math.round(Math.random()*101),
      easyRand6 = Math.round(Math.random()*101),
      easyRandd = `rgb(${easyRand4}, ${easyRand5}, ${easyRand6})`;
      easyRand7 = Math.round(Math.random()*102),
      easyRand8 = Math.round(Math.random()*102),
      easyRand9 = Math.round(Math.random()*103),
      easyRanddd = `rgb(${easyRand7}, ${easyRand8}, ${easyRand9})`,
      // Hard Random Colors 
      hardRand1 = Math.round(Math.random()*100),
      hardRand2 = Math.round(Math.random()*130),
      hardRand3 = Math.round(Math.random()*190),
      hardRand = `rgb(${hardRand1}, ${hardRand2}, ${hardRand3})`;
      hardRand4 = Math.round(Math.random()*87),
      hardRand5 = Math.round(Math.random()*77),
      hardRand6 = Math.round(Math.random()*158),
      hardRandd = `rgb(${hardRand4}, ${hardRand5}, ${hardRand6})`;
      hardRand7 = Math.round(Math.random()*89),
      hardRand8 = Math.round(Math.random()*199),
      hardRand9 = Math.round(Math.random()*121),
      hardRanddd = `rgb(${hardRand7}, ${hardRand8}, ${hardRand9})`,
      // Colors styling
      colors = document.querySelector('.colors'),
      allColors = document.querySelectorAll('.color');

let guessesLeft = 3


      


easyBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  easyBtn.style.background = 'rgb(233, 150, 333)';

  hardBtn.style.background = 'rgb(233, 230, 333)';

  addNewColors();
})

hardBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  hardBtn.style.background = 'rgb(233, 150, 333)';

  easyBtn.style.background = 'rgb(233, 230, 333)';

  addHardColors();
})

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  rgb.innerHTML = `<h1>${randd}</h1>`;
  color1.style.backgroundColor = `${rand}`;
  color2.style.backgroundColor = `${randd}`
  color3.style.backgroundColor = `${randdd}`
  
  for (var i = colorsDiv.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    colorsDiv.appendChild(colorsDiv.children[[Math.random() * i | 0]]);
}
})

newGame.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.location.reload();
})

function addHardColors() {
  rgb.innerHTML = `<h1>${easyRand}</h1>`;
  color1.innerHTML = `<h1 class="color color1" style="background-color: ${easyRand};">`;
  color2.innerHTML = `
  <h1 class="color color2" style="background-color: ${easyRandd};">`;
  color3.innerHTML = `<h1 class="color color3" style="background-color: ${easyRanddd};">`;
}

function addNewColors() {
  rgb.innerHTML = `<h1>${hardRandd}</h1>`;
  color1.innerHTML = `<h1 class="color color1" style="background-color: ${hardRand};">`;
  color2.innerHTML = `
  <h1 class="color color2" style="background-color: ${hardRandd};">`;
  color3.innerHTML = `<h1 class="color color3" style="background-color: ${hardRanddd};">`;
}

allColors.forEach(function(color) {
  color.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let guess = e.target.style.backgroundColor;

    let winningColor = document.querySelector('.rgb').textContent;
  
    console.log(guess)
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background: rgb(233, 150, 333);
  height: 30vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  line-height: 7rem;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.title {
  color: white;
}

.buttons {
  background:rgb(233, 230, 333);
  height: 5vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.difficulty {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  right: 190px;
}

.btn {
  width: 100px;
  background:rgb(233, 230, 333);
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

.colors {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgb(233, 230, 200);
  height: 65vh;
}

.color {
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 400px;
}

.rgb {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.new {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 761px) {
  .color {
    width: 230px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="rgb.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Varela+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <h1 class="title">RGB Guesser</h1>
      <h1 class="rgb"></h1>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="buttons">
    <button class="btn new">NEW GAME</button>
    <div class="difficulty">
    <button class="easy btn">EASY</button>
    <button class="hard btn">HARD</button>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="colors-container">
  <section class="colors">
    <h1 class="color color1" style="background-color: red;"></h1>
    <h1 class="color color2" style="background-color: purple"></h1>
    <h1 class="color color3" style="background-color: blue;"></h1>
  </section>
  </div>

  <script src="rgb.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The maximum value for R, G or B in a RGB colour is 255.  Some of the colours your code generates have R, G and B values in excess of 255, so your browser will limit them to 255.  Is this the problem you're having?

Comment: @LukeWoodward Yes! Thank you. I didn't know this.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value of R, G or B in an RGB colour is 255.

However, in lines such as

```js
      rand1 = Math.round(Math.random()*300),
      rand2 = Math.round(Math.random()*300),
      rand3 = Math.round(Math.random()*300),
      rand = `rgb(${rand1}, ${rand2}, ${rand3})`,
```

you may end up with `rand1`, `rand2` or `rand3` having values larger than 255.

Your browser will limit R, G and B values to 255, so if any of `rand1` to `rand3` are larger than this, then the colour shown by the browser will differ from the colour set in your code.

The fix is straightforward: don't generate colours with the R, G or B values larger than 255.